# What is the meaning of SYMLINK in udev rules?

Tags: drivers, usb, udev, devices, usb-device

I've been trying to write a USB driver for a device, but none of the methods (libhid, libusb-0.1, libusb-1.0) I've tried work. I've written usb drivers before. I can also communicate with the device via ethernet fine. But however I try via USB, I always get "Resource temporarily unavailable".

So I think something it taking control of the device when it connects via USB.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 2457:2003  
    (yes the rest of line is blank)

$ usb-devices
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=04 Dev#= 10 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2457 ProdID=2003 Rev=01.17
S:  Manufacturer=Ocean Optics
S:  Product=OceanHDX
S:  SerialNumber=HDX00415
C:  #Ifs= 0 Cfg#= 0 Atr= MxPwr=
I:  If#=0x Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=() Sub= Prot= Driver=
    (note: it doesn't say Driver=(none) like some other devices)

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-oceanoptics.rules
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2457", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2003", SYMLINK+="oceanhdx-%n", MODE:="0666"

$ hd /dev/oceanhdx-6 
000000 12 01 00 02 00 00 00 40 57 24 03 20 17 01 01 02  >.......@W$. ....<
000010 03 01 09 02 20 00 01 01 04 80 fa 09 04 00 00 02  >.... ...........<
000020 ff 00 00 05 07 05 01 02 00 02 00 07 05 81 02 00  >................<
000030 02 00                                            >..<
```

So my question is: if I can `cat /dev/ocean-hdx-6`, there's clearly a driver answering. Who is that, what piece of code is that ? Is `Driver=` different from `Driver=(none)` ? `lsof /dev/ocean-hdx-6` yields nothing.

```
$ sudo udevadm monitor --udev --property
UDEV  [2454.018408] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/010
DEVTYPE=usb_device
PRODUCT=2457/2003/117
TYPE=0/0/0
BUSNUM=003
DEVNUM=010
SEQNUM=9149
USEC_INITIALIZED=2454010185
ID_VENDOR=Ocean_Optics
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Ocean\x20Optics
ID_VENDOR_ID=2457
ID_MODEL=OceanHDX
ID_MODEL_ENC=OceanHDX
ID_MODEL_ID=2003
ID_REVISION=0117
ID_SERIAL=Ocean_Optics_OceanHDX_HDX00415
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=HDX00415
ID_BUS=usb
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
DRIVER=usb
MAJOR=189
MINOR=265
DEVLINKS=/dev/oceanhdx-6

UDEV  [2454.020344] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PRODUCT=2457/2003/117
TYPE=0/0/0
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v2457p2003d0117dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
SEQNUM=9150
USEC_INITIALIZED=2454020187

UDEV  [2454.024168] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/010
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
PRODUCT=2457/2003/117
TYPE=0/0/0
BUSNUM=003
DEVNUM=010
SEQNUM=9151
USEC_INITIALIZED=2454010185
ID_VENDOR=Ocean_Optics
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Ocean\x20Optics
ID_VENDOR_ID=2457
ID_MODEL=OceanHDX
ID_MODEL_ENC=OceanHDX
ID_MODEL_ID=2003
ID_REVISION=0117
ID_SERIAL=Ocean_Optics_OceanHDX_HDX00415
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=HDX00415
ID_BUS=usb
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
MAJOR=189
MINOR=265
DEVLINKS=/dev/oceanhdx-6
```

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong, but the question title seems misleading. The answer to _that_ question is easy: when the `udev` rule matches (i.e. is executed for) a discovered device, a symlink with name `oceanhdx-<number>` will be created that points to the "raw" devicefile, and where `<number>` will be replaced by the kernel's internal device number. This function, however, is mainly there for a more "human-readable" `/dev/` filesystem, and AFAIU doesn't provide a clue to your problem.

Comment: So is using libusb_open(PID, VID) technically the same as open("/dev/oceanhdx-6") or do they have different meanings/functionalities ?